# Ionic (Android) with webRTC. No output audio

Tags: android, cordova, audio, ionic-framework, webrtc

I have a problem with webRTC audio on my Ionic Android app. I'm using the same code on a regular website I've made, and on an Ionic iOS app. Both the website and iOS app works perfect, but the Android app won't play the sound from the remote stream. I'm able to receive video and send audio and video. The website and iOS communicates just fine.

I've found a warning in logcat: (http://pastebin.com/Xku13haM)

```
[WARNING:webrtcsession.cc(1569)] Candidate has unknown component: Cand[920847596:2:udp:1686052606:xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:50008:stun:192.168.0.198:50008::] for content: audio
```

And:

```
W/chromium(32075): [WARNING:webrtcvoiceengine.cc(2877)] SetOutputVolumePan(1, 1, 1) failed, err=8040
```

Android permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

[edit] I use crosswalk [/edit]

Comment: I have the same issue with Crosswalk 20+. Crosswalk 19 works for me though. Do you have any updates on this issue?